# Ionic2 - how to read the 'URL' typed by the user?

Tags: url, ionic2

I am developing an hybrid Ionic2 application & website to show data sent by numerous connected objects.

Each object has a unique ID. 
Data can be accessed:

- through the application, by entering the ID in a dedicated form
- through a link (QR code) to a virtual web page : app.site.com/I_need_a_way_to_read_the_ID.

So I need a way to "recognize" that I am aking for ID (difficult), and put the ID in the form mentionned above (easy).

If the QRCode links to "app.site.com/ID", my application must be aware of all IDs, so I did not find a way to make it work.

But if the QRCode links to "app.site.com/?ID", then Ionic considers that I am landing on the home page. 
But I did not find any way to get the full URL, analize it and grab the ID.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well I diged further.

The answer is about DeepLinks. No need to use the Deeplinks plugin (which I was not able to configure reliably) as Deeplinks are embedded in Ionic 2.

[The easiest solution is described here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-deeplinker-in-browser/75787/2).

In two words:

```
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, DeepLinkConfig } from 'ionic-angular';
...
IonicModule.forRoot(App, {}, 
    {links: [
        { component: targetPage, name: "ID", segment: "id/:name" }
    ]}
)
```

Then use the following link and ça-roule-ma-poule ! :

```
app.site.com/#/id/my_id
```